# Grunt Task Will Not Execute Modules From Node Code Referenced With Require

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have the following grunt task:

```
    module.exports = function(grunt) {
    var info = 'Syncs, updates English translations and downloads Chinese translations.';    

    grunt.registerTask('translations', info, function() {
        require('../../node/poeditor');
    });
};
```

I want that require to execute the code within that node module, its laid out like this:

```
var querystring = require('querystring'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https');

// Sync Terms
console.log('Syncing Terms...');
var requestConfig = {
    options: {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': 0
        },
        host: 'poeditor.com',
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/api/',
        port: '443'
    },
    data: {
        api_token: API_KEY,
        action: 'sync_terms',
        id: PROJECT_ID,
        data: ''
    }
};

fs.readFile('public/js/languages/en.json', 'utf8', function(error, data) { console.log(data);
});
```

The problem is no modules referenced in the above are being executed at all, what am I missing? Is there something special I have to do in Grunt or when requiring a module that requires other modules to execute code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was doing asynchronous operations so I instead called my task like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('translations', info, function() {
        require('../../node/poeditor')(this);
    });
```

Pass that scope via the module:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {...
```

And then assigned done like so:

```
var done = grunt.async();
```

And on my last asynchronous callback called that like so:

```
done();
```

So basically I had to follow this:
http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#why-doesn-t-my-asynchronous-task-complete